# How to create Store and Model for following data?

Tags: extjs4, modal-dialog, store

I am fetching data with JSON call and setting it to different store, now I have modified JSON structure to fulfill one more requirement which is ProgreesBar data.
Do I have to create new store or modal for the data or I can fetch it from store.

```
{
  "data": [{
    "firstRun": {
      "progress": 0,
      "settingList": [{
        "settingName": "BoxTone Database Password",
        "cssClass": "neutral",
        "id": "linl_boxtone_db_passwoed"
      }, {
        "settingName": "Email Notification",
        "cssClass": "fault",
        "id": "email_notification_link"
      }, {
        "settingName": "User and Group Sync",
        "cssClass": "neutral",
        "id": "link_user_and_group_sync",
        "listItem": [{
          "settingName": "User and Group Sync from ActiveDirectory",
          "cssClass": "neutral",
          "id": "link_user_and_group_sync_ad",
          "listItem": "AL"
        }, {
          "settingName": "Add Groups",
          "cssClass": "neutral",
          "id": "link_add_groups",
          "listItem": "AL"
        }]
      }, {
        "settingName": "ActiveSync Log Share",
        "cssClass": "neutral",
        "id": "link_activesync_log_share"
      }]
    },
    "operate": {
      "progress": 0.04,
      "settingList": [{
        "settingName": "SNMP Alerting",
        "cssClass": "neutral",
        "id": "lnk_snmp_alerting"
      }, {
        "settingName": "BlackBerry Servers",
        "cssClass": "neutral",
        "id": "lnk_BlackBerryServers",
        "listItem": [{
          "settingName": "BES 5.x Servers",
          "cssClass": "neutral",
          "id": "lnk_BESServers",
          "listItem": "AL"
        }, {
          "settingName": "BES Logs",
          "cssClass": "neutral",
          "id": "lnk_BESLogs",
          "listItem": "AL"
        }, {
          "settingName": "BES SNMP Alerting",
          "cssClass": "neutral",
          "id": "lnk_BESSNMPAlerting",
          "listItem": "AL"
        }]
      }, {
        "settingName": "Good For Enterprise (GFE) Servers",
        "cssClass": "mixed",
        "id": "gmServer",
        "listItem": [{
          "settingName": "GFE Good Messaging Control (GMC) Servers",
          "cssClass": "fault",
          "id": "gmcServer",
          "listItem": "AL"
        }, {
          "settingName": "GFE Good Mobile Messaging (GMM) Servers",
          "cssClass": "saved",
          "id": "gmmServer",
          "listItem": "AL"
        }, {
          "settingName": "GFE Load Balancing",
          "cssClass": "neutral",
          "id": "gfe_load_balancing",
          "listItem": "AL"
        }]
      }, {
        "settingName": "Good Dynamics Servers",
        "cssClass": "neutral",
        "id": "lnk_GoodDynamicsServers",
        "listItem": [{
          "settingName": "Good Control (GC) Servers",
          "cssClass": "neutral",
          "id": "lnk_GoodControlServers",
          "listItem": "AL"
        }]
      }, {
        "settingName": "Microsoft Exchange Activesync",
        "cssClass": "neutral",
        "id": "lnk_MicrosoftExchangeActivesync",
        "listItem": [{
          "settingName": "HTTP Error Logs",
          "cssClass": "neutral",
          "id": "lnk_HTTPErrorLogs",
          "listItem": "AL"
        }, {
          "settingName": "BES",
          "cssClass": "neutral",
          "id": "lnk_BES",
          "listItem": "AL"
        }]
      }]
    }
  }],
  "success": true
}
```

Comment: Depends on how you need to use the data. If the data is already in a store, and you only need values, then yes you can simply retrieve it and use it. If you need to use the data in a model/store-like manner, then creating a new store with a different model is probably what you need to do. Without knowing your exact requirement, it's tough to tell, though, since you can do plenty in ExtJS without a model and store (and also a ton with them).

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the raw data from the store if you don't have 'progress' in your Model.  However, this would NOT be highly suggested as you won't be able to interact with the data to the same extent you would if it was in your Model through any ExtJS methods.